# Using reflection based static invocation instead of interfaces

Tags: java, model-view-controller, interface, static-methods

My question is a general design question in Java. In typical controller based designs (lets say MVC) , Controllers generally create instances of actions and invoke a method that is implemented from a interface (lets say execute() of Action interface).

Why do we need to create unnecessary objects, why not use static invocation and eliminate the need to implement a interface?

like the example below. Same way as every Java program is expected to have a main() method, every action method is expected to have execute()

```
class MyActionClass {
    public static void execute() {
        System.out.println("Hello from execute()!!");
    }
}

public class StaticTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws SecurityException
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
                        NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
                        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("MyActionClass");
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("execute");
        method.invoke(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: The reflection instantiates objects too.

Comment: Radiodef that is true, I think I am finding answer for the question after self deliberation. Probably that is the reason we have "singleton" in Spring framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well because Reflection API is much slower than method calling as when using reflection, the compiler can do no optimization whatsoever as it can have no real idea about what you are doing.

By having an interface and multiple concrete classes which implement it, we can have the advantage of polymorphic behavior. Add [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in the equation, and you can directly work with your interfaces without actually needing to know which concrete class method you are invoking. The added benefit is that the compiler will be able to optimize your code making it run much faster compared to using Reflection API.

As of Java 8, we can have static and instance method implementations in interfaces. Here's a demo:

```
public class InterfaceDemo
{
  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    XYZ.executeStatic("Hello");

    XYZ object = new Implementer();
    object.executeInstance("Message");
  }
}

interface XYZ
{
  static void executeStatic(String message)
  {
    System.out.println("Static: " + message);
  }

  default void executeInstance(String message)
  {
    System.out.println("Instance: " + message);
  }
}

class Implementer implements XYZ {}
```

Then there are functional interfaces like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Returnable<T>
{
  public T value();
}
```

Which allows the creation of different implementations using lambda expressions like:

```
Returnable<Integer> integerReturnable = () -> 42;
Returnable<String> stringReturnable = () -> "Hello";
```

And use like:

```
System.out.println(integerReturnable.value()); // Prints 42
System.out.println(stringReturnable.value()); // Prints Hello
```

By the way, if there are lots of objects that need to be created, we use [Object Pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) or something similar, and if there are lots of similar objects, we use [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to minimise memory usage while still keeping speed.

Comment: Agreed with need for factory pattern when we are instantiating lot of objects. But my question here is that these action classes generally have no local storage, all that consumer want to do is execute some action, why do consumers need to instantiate objects when they can utilize static invocation? I believe all these frameworks already use reflection to instantiate appropriate action classes, so there is no question of reflection being slow.

Comment: Well what framework are you particularly talking about? Cause in MVC architecture, models and views are not be created by Reflection, but by object instantiation and they are then used using conventional method invocations. A framework can use Reflection to instantiate methods on objects, but there are lot of other simpler and faster ways of handling such situations. Reflection is slow compared to direct method calling and object instantiation, and that is why the general consensus is not biased towards using it. Reflection API has its advantages, but not particularly in this situation.

Comment: Agreed answer for my question was Flyweight, I was not thinking eight yesterday night as I pointed out to Radiodef.

Comment: Well I don't see where you mentioned to Radiodef that you weren't talking about Java 8, but then again, it was hard to get what you were actually asking in the first place. :D So I ended up telling even the surrounding aspects of your question in order to hit the bulls eye. Glad you agreed to one part of my answer as the answer to your question, though other parts of my answer are useful in their respect.